# Why am I seeing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions on only certain Sony-Ericsson phones?

Tags: android, sony

In the field, I'm receiving an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions with Result=3 on specific Sony-Ericsson phones (X10i, X15i, E15a).  However, when I tried this app using one of Sony-Ericsson's Developer World loaner phones, it worked perfectly.

Does anyone know whether Sony-Ericsson had originally customized their implementation of Android and have since removed this customization?  Should I worry about this exception?

Comment: Um, where is this happening? What line of code? What methods are you calling? If your app is crashing frequently, then yes, you should probably worry about it.

Comment: Since the log does not show any of our code, I don't know exactly where in our code it is happening. I am using ACRA, so by using flags I set up in the code, I am able to determine that they are getting part way into our initialization code. I will go back to ACRA and see if I can set up some better error trapping. Just hoping someone else has seen this behavior with S-E phones.

Comment: Hmm, I have no experience with SE or whatever ACRA is, but I would imagine it should still show a .java file where the exception is occuring, and a line number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe has been seen on some applications but has been considered as a problem in the Android framework of the Android SW initially taken for the X10 minis.
If you check the build number of the phone that is working, and compare it with with non-working phones,you will end up with different build numbers.

Kind regards
  /Johan, Sony Ericsson Developer Support.